# NSNotificationCenter - list of default events?

Tags: ios, nsnotificationcenter, nsnotifications

Is there a list of any default notifications that may be published via NSNotificationCenter on iOS?  I'm wondering if there are any observable events for application startup, etc. that may be observed via NSNotificationCenter.  I wasn't able to find any references online, but thought someone here may know.  Thanks for any help you can give!

Comment: Look at the docs for `UIApplication`. There is a list of application notifications you can listen on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are tons of notifications that get posted by various components in the iOS SDK. The documentation can be found with the class posting the notification, not NSNotificationCenter itself.

For example, you're looking for these: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIApplication_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006728-CH3-DontLinkElementID_4